# My java code is not working (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, api, spotify

I'm trying to learn how to use the Spotify API, but their [sample code](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java) is not working.

I'm using Netbeans 8.1, I did import the .jar files and it's saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/json/JSON` in the `Api api = Api.builder()` line.

```
import com.wrapper.spotify.Api;
import com.wrapper.spotify.methods.AlbumRequest;
import com.wrapper.spotify.models.Album;
import java.util.List;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an API instance. The default instance connects to https://api.spotify.com/.
    Api api = Api.builder()
            .clientId("<secret>")
            .clientSecret("<secret>")
            .redirectURI("<secret>")
            .build();

    // Create a request object for the type of request you want to make
    AlbumRequest request = api.getAlbum("7e0ij2fpWaxOEHv5fUYZjd").build();

    // Retrieve an album
    try {
        Album album = request.get();

        // Print the genres of the album
        List<String> genres = album.getGenres();
        for (String genre : genres) {
            System.out.println(genre);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not get albums.");
    }

}
```

Comment: @user7294900 Actualy, after I learned more about maven I could see the problem, but yes it helped.

Answer (score 1):

`net/sf/json/JSON` class is inside json-lib jar

In the sample you need to add its dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Check that you are using the maven's [pom.xml](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/blob/master/pom.xml) in the example.

Comment: I didn't undertand this part, I'm a new programmer, how can I add the dependency?

Comment: Read the readme and install using maven or gradle https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

these could be the reasons:
1.Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time.
2. If a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime.

there are several ways rectify it.

1. if it is maven project then add net.sf.json-lib dependency in your pom.xml:
2. else add jar to project lib folder
3. add the jar to class path from build configuration

Answer (score 0):

If it's your maven project then add the dependecy in pom.xml or you can download the external jar and attach into the project.